# django-extensions shell_plus --kernel specify connection file

Tags: python, django, ipython, jupyter, django-extensions

I would like to use jupyter-hub start and interact with django ipython kernels.

Django extensions allows me to create an ipython kernel via the `manage.py shell_plus --kernel` command line, however this doesn't allow me to specify the connection file, which is required for jupyter-hub kernel specification.

For example I would like to Specify my own custom kernel type similarly to this:

```
{
"display_name": "Django",
"language": "python",
"codemirror_mode": {
    "version": 3,
    "name": "ipython"
},
"argv": [
    "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django/bin/python",
    "/home/me/django/manage.py",
    "shell_plus",
    "--kernel",
    "-f",
    "{connection_file}"
    ]
}
```

However it doesn't look like the `--kernel` option allows me to pass additional kwags.

I've taken a quick look at the source for `django-extensions` and `ipython`, but can't see an easy fix. Anyone have any ideas.

I think it would be super useful to be able to connect to a django shell from Jupyter-hub, and it seems like the functionality is pretty close.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested, I fixed this by adding a `--connection_file` option to the shell_plus command in django-extension, which then forwards the filename to the kernel.
I can then define my django kernel for Jupyter-hub as the following.

```
{
"display_name": "Django",
"language": "python",
"codemirror_mode": {
    "version": 3,
    "name": "ipython"
},
"argv": [
    "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django/bin/python",
    "/home/me/django/manage.py",
    "shell_plus",
    "--kernel",
    "--connection_file",
    "{connection_file}"
    ]
}
```

See my branch on [github](https://github.com/robitnik/django-extensions/commit/b8b53f0b74a21a2ecb160d97b05edd1d56cb83d6) for the changes.

Comment: Why not offer this as a patch back to django-extensions?

Comment: A PR was issued and merged: https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/pull/910

Comment: In django-extensions version 1.7.4 the parameter's name is `--connection-file` not `--connection_file` (hyphen not underscore)